# WPF MVVM and Behaviors - is it a good practice to use AssociatedObject.DataContext

Tags: wpf, mvvm

When using WPF behaviors - is it a good practice (MVVM-wise) to use a ViewModel defined for AssociatedObject.DataContext? Like this event handler in the Behavior:

```
    private void Plate_MouseLeftButtonDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        UserControl userControl = AssociatedObject as UserControl;
        Border borderParent = userControl.Parent as Border;
        PlateViewModel plateViewModel = userControl.DataContext as PlateViewModel;

        plateViewModel.ElementSelectedItem.Caption = "Selected Item";
    }
```

Comment: You can use but don't assume that should be a `PlateViewModel`. Also using `userControl.Parent as Border` doesn't sounds right for me. That's depending on the UI more..

Comment: Imho Behaviours shouldn't be aware of a specific ViewModel, like in your case. ViewModels are very application dependent. Behaviours, UserControls (as in EditBox, ListView etc, not as View for a certain ViewModel), Triggers and action on the other side, should are part of the "View" layer and should be able to be reused across applications. When you assume a certain ViewModel in your behaviour, you can't reuse them in other applications anymore